# Tkinter dropdown Menu with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, tkinter

I would like to have a Dropdown Menu in Tkinter, that includes the shortcut key associated with this command. Is this possible?

How would I also add the underline under a certain character, to allow for `Alt-F-S` (File->Save)?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        fileMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=1,
                             command=quit, accelerator="Ctrl+Q")
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        self.bind_all("<Control-q>", self.quit)

    def quit(self, event):
        print("quitting...")
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, how did you find that?

Comment: @CMC: I didn't find it, I know it. I've been doing Tk development with Tcl since '95 and translating that knowledge to python is very straight-forward.

Comment: Oh, okay. Also, how would I underline a character menu item? selection_present returns True/False, but I want something like a 2-tuple containing the start & end values, or the selected text.

Comment: @CMC: are you wanting to underline more than one character? The underline option (as in the example) allows you to only underline a single character.

Comment: Ah, I see now, I was interpreting the underline option as a boolean value...thanks.

Comment: Here's a tutorial that provides a bit more context and walks you through the hot keys: http://zetcode.com/tkinter/menustoolbars/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as filed

root = Tk()
root.title("My Python Tkinter Application")
root.minsize(800,600)

def openfile():
    fn = filed.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text Files","*.txt")], title="Open File")
    f = open(fn, "r").read()
    print(f)

def init():
    menu = Menu(root)
    filemenu = Menu(menu)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Open (⌘O)", command=openfile)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    root.config(menu=menu)
def key():
    print("Key Pressed: "+repr(event.char))
root.bind("<Key>", key)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code press ctrl+e to exit the programmme

```
from tkinter import *

class MainApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.menubar = Menu(self.root)
        self.fileMenu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=False)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.fileMenu)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", accelerator="Ctrl+E")
        self.root.config(menu=self.menubar)

        self.root.bind_all("<Control-e>", lambda event: self.root.quit())
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp(Tk())
```