# Tkinter bind Mac OS "command+q"

Tags: macos, tkinter, bind, exit, shortcut

I'm trying to "stop" the root window exiting when I press "Command+q" but it's impossible.

The other key shortcuts work on my Mac OS, even in Windows/Linux, "Alt+F4" bind is possible to "capture", but in Mac OS is impossible for me.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: So, the shortcut as used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3485519/16775594) (`<Control-q>`) doesn't work for you?

Comment: Doesn't work because the entire program is destroyed instantly. If I click the X in windows corner, the system protocol "WM_DELETE_WINDOW" works and I can save my data before exiting of my app. I think "Command+Q" in Mac OS is a priority shortcut and I can't use with Tkinter. Mac OS forces exiting without system protocol...

Comment: Have you tried using `return "break"` at the end of your `quit()` function? Or does it not get called at all?

Comment: Is not called. The entire program is destroyed immediately. Is called if I use X click (protocol "WM_DELETE_WINDOW"). Otherwise the entire program closes immediately.

Comment: Hmm. Then maybe there's something in your system settings that needs to be changed. I don't use Mac, so I don't know where that would be.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I'll keep trying a solution

Comment: Please post that in an answer, not a comment, so that you can accept it and so that other users know that the question has been answered satisfactorily. See [answer] for more information on writing answers.

Comment: sorry :)   already done

Answer (score 1):

Finally I discovered the solution. The solution is as it must be always. You have to activate a "Mac Menu" to activate system functions like Command-Q behaviour:

```
    mac_app_menu = Menu(menubar , name = "apple")
    menubar.add_cascade(menu = mac_app_menu) 
    root.createcommand("tk::mac::ShowPreferences" , lambda: "whatever") 
    root.createcommand("tk::mac::Quit" , lambda: "before quit things")
```

Comment: What is the definition of `menubar` in your code above?

Comment: Is your main menubar in your app. Defined by "menubar = Menu(root_window)"

Comment: Got it, tyvm. Your answer above helped me with a similar Tkinter problem where I had to trap the `tk::mac::Quit` event.

Comment: Cool! I'm a beginner and I like Tkinter but isn't documented enough. I recommend you buy some beginner book. For me have been the best way to solve a lot of doubts

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have programmed other GUI frameworks/toolkits before, so I just need to navigate the platform-specific nuances/quirks of Tkinter. A nice python GUI framework that I'd recommend is Kivy.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I knew about Kivy. It will be the next challenge: portate my Tkinter app to mobile phones :)